# Error trying to import a component from another folder (react - native)

Tags: react-native

This is my simple code and its giving me that error, can someone help me?

[App.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nwf6F.png)

[comp1.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WKrA.png)

[folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXFHs.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlqzN.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create functional component - you need to create it smth like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";

const TextComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Text>Hello</Text>
  );
};

export default TextComponent
```

You should read about difference between function/class components/functional components.

Start from here:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/view

Comment: I used your code but got the same problem. I followed a step by step, writing the exact same thing, and in the person of the video it worked and mine didn't. I do not know what is happening.

Comment: @DanielD first of all you wrote func without name and trying to call it like component. Thats why our code doesn't work. On comp1.js screenshot you didn't save changes or did you? When you just created new project - it worked?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified your function name, so
change your `comp1.js` function likewise :

```
const C1 = () => {
  return (
    <Text>Hello</Text>
  );
};

export default C1;
```